# AES (block size 128-bit) in CBC mode with PKCS#5 padding in PHP 8

Tags: php, encryption, opayo, php-8, pkcs#5

Trying to send the encrypted data from a laravel php8 app to sage pay or opayo.

I cannot Figure out how to perform AES (block size 128-bit) in CBC mode with PKCS#5 padding in PHP8.

Openssl appears to only let us pad in PKCS#7 and older PHP examples and method all rely on deprecated / removed functions.

```
 $cryptFieldString = http_build_query($cryptFields);
 $encodedCrypt = openssl_encrypt($cryptFieldString, 'aes-128-cbc', $key, 0, $key);
 $crypt = '@'.strtoupper(bin2hex($encodedCrypt));
```

$encodedCrypt variable will always return PKCS#7 or raw data.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by PKCS#5 padding in the context of AES? Maybe you confuse PKCS#5 and PKCS#7 padding, see [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/9043).

Answer (score 0):

PKCS#5 padding is added just in combination of bin2hex and openssl_encrypt, you don't need to use any other functions. However, you have to check encoding supported something like this

```
if( in_array( 'AES-128-CBC', openssl_get_cipher_methods() ) ) {
            $cipher_method = 'AES-128-CBC';
        }

        if( in_array( 'aes-128-cbc', openssl_get_cipher_methods() ) ) {
            $cipher_method = 'aes-128-cbc';
        }
```

So you can use `bin2hex( openssl_encrypt( $input, $cipher_method, $securekey, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $securekey ) )`

Comment: Can you [edit] your answer to explain what is different with the method that he used, and how to use it ?